# How to get image count in android using intent for the image selection

Tags: android, kotlin

When i was selecting multiple images from the photos folder in gallery, Only single image was loaded. How to solve the problem. Can i get the image count?

```
            if(data.getData() != null ) 
                 {

                val imagePath = data.getData().getPath()


                  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == SELECT_PICTURES) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(data.getClipData() != null) {
                int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount(); //evaluate the count before the for loop --- otherwise, the count is evaluated every loop.
                for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)  
                    Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    //do something with the image (save it to some directory or whatever you need to do with it here) 
                }
            } else if(data.getData() != null) {
                String imagePath = data.getData().getPath();
                //do something with the image (save it to some directory or whatever you need to do with it here)
            }
        }
    }
}
```